# How to export model with custom material?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, export

this seems like such a simple "just google it" thing, but nothing I've found has worked for me.

I have a model with a custom material that I want to export into Unity.

[image]

I've applied an image onto the model using the Diffuse BSDF shader and setting the Image Texture under color, and it looks fine in Blender (fine for my horrible standards), but when I export to fbx it's just a gray colorless model, even if I follow the advice of setting 'Path Mode' to 'Copy' and checking 'Embed Textures'.
Some people say to bake but I haven't been able to figure out how to make that work either.

Thank you

Comment: Try using a Principled node instead of Diffuse and hook the texture up to the Base Color. See [Import & Export of Node Shaders](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.91/addons/import_export/node_shaders_info.html).